# How to optimize slow Mongo MapReduce with dynamic groups

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, group-by, mapreduce

I'm pretty new working with mongo, but have plenty of experience with relational databases.

I have about 85000 **events** hosted in **locations**, each with an associated **weight**. For a heatmap, I now need to group the accumulated weight of events within a region of latitude/longitude.

In **mongo**, it currently looks like this (no indexes, tried them without success):

```
events: {
  latitude: Number,
  longitude: Number,
  weight: Number
}

db.events.mapReduce(function() {
    emit({
      latitudeGroup: Math.floor(this.latitude / 1.2),
      longitudeGroup: Math.floor(this.longitude / 1.8)
    }, this.weight);
  }, function(key, values) {
    return Array.sum(values)
  }, { out: 'inline' })
```

Note that the 1.2 and 1.8 are arbitrary and dynamic, caching the results for every possible combination would be *very* memory consuming. The query takes **1500ms**, which is much too long for a realtime web application.

Coming from a relational world, I tried the same in **Postgres**:

```
CREATE TABLE event (
  id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  latitude NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  longitude NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  weight INTEGER NOT NULL
);

SELECT floor(latitude / 1.2) AS latitudeGroup, floor(longitude / 1.8) AS longitudeGroup, SUM(weight) FROM event GROUP BY latitudeGroup, longitudeGroup;
```

This takes a more acceptable **400ms**, without any utilization of Postgres GiST capabilities.

I'm just wondering if I'm missing something on the mongo side. I've looked into the **aggregation framework** but don't think that what I'm doing is possible with it.

I'd be very happy if there would be some way to make this work with reasonable performance. It's a key feature for a prototype I'm working on and a database switch wouldn't be too costly at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should test with index.

Also have you tried to use the aggregation framework instead of MapReduce?

```
db.events.aggregate([
  { $group : {
  _id : { "latitude" : "$latitude", "longitude" : "$longitude" } ,   
      weight : { "$sum" : { $multiply : ["$weight",1.2]} }
  }}
])
```

The aggregation framework use the same mechanism that the core query engine of the database (not like MapReduce that use V8 engine)

Comment: Thanks for the hints - I've already tried indexes to no success. Also as stated above I don't think what I'm doing is possible with the aggregation framework, your query yields very different results.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like below and see if it works.

```
db.events.aggregate([
  { $project : {
    weight:1,
    lat: {$divide:["$latitude",1.2]},
    long: {$divide:["$longitude",1.8]}
  }},
  { $group : {
  _id : { "lat" : "$lat", "long" : "$long" } ,   
  weight : { "$sum" : "$weight"} }
  }}
])
```

Comment: A division alone won't create the proper groups. To imitate the floor-behavior above, I would probably have to substract the modulo from the result, like this: group = latitude / 1.2 - latitude % 1.2.

Comment: Agreed !! You might have to do some tweaking to get the floor behavior but I believe it should be doable with aggregation. You can even check the operators which could be used [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)